# Concatenar filas en archivo Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Necesito generar un script de linux que concatene informacion. Tengo un archivo (arch1.txt) que contiene nombres y apellidos:

```
Juan Perez
Ana Lopez
```

y tengo otro script que al ejecutarlo me devuelve una línea que contiene la edad de las personas en el archivo arch1.txt. Por ejemplo el resultado para las dos personas existentes es el siguiente:

```
1711089378 22 H
0976324852 25 M
```

Necesito concatenar estos datos y que el arch1.txt contenga ahora esto

```
Juan Perez 20
Ana Lopez 25
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo ejecutas ese otro script? Es decir, ¿cuál es el comando que usas para obtener las edades? ¿Cómo relacionas una línea con la otra?

Answer (score 6):

```
arch1.txt    arch2.txt
---------    ---------
Juan Perez   1711089378 22 H
Ana Lopez    0976324852 25 M
```

Si ejecutas lo siguiente te mostrara el resultado que quieres

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$2}' arch1.txt arch2.txt

Juan Perez 22
Ana Lopez 25
```

`NR` Da el numero total de registros procesados

`FNR` Da el numero total de registros para cada fichero

`{a[NR]=$0;next}` llena la matriz `a` con los registros procesados del fichero `arch1.txt`

`next` hace que awk detenga el procesamiento del fichero actual y pase al siguiente fichero en este caso `arch2.txt`

`{print a[FNR],$2}` imprime los resultados añadiendo la palabra o texto que se encuentra en el campo `$2` del fichero `arch2.txt` que en este caso es la edad

[Awk Built-in Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_built_in_variables.htm)

Para guardar el resultado obtenido en `arch1.txt` puedes usar un tercer fichero digamos `output.txt` para almacenar estos resultados y luego moverlos a `arch1.txt`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$2}' arch1.txt arch2.txt > output.txt && mv output.txt arch1.txt
```

Luego puedes mirar el contenido de `arch1.txt` y tendrás el resultado que quieres

```
$ cat arch1.txt

Juan Perez 22
Ana Lopez 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa es el comando `join` que por defecto "une" los archivos con base en la primera columna, por eso usamos `nl` para pasar cada archivo con las líneas numeradas como primera columna. Para la salida le decimos que queremos el campo 2 y 3 del archivo 1 (`1.2,1.3`) y el campo 3 del archivo 2 (`2.3`).

```
join -o 1.2,1.3,2.3 <(nl arch1.txt) <(nl arch2.txt)
```