# Búsqueda avanzada en Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Tengo dos archivos, en el primero una lista de reportes y en el segundo una lista de empresas por ejemplo.

archivo1.csv

```
20170112;compra;articulos papeleria;Papeleria Pepito
20170112;compra;tinta impresoras;Distribuidora de todito
20170214;venta;juego de sala;Perico de los palotes
```

archivo2.csv

```
Papeleria Pepito;/tmp/transacciones/PapeleriaPepito
Distribuidora de todito;/tmp/transacciones/DistribuidoraTodito
```

Lo que necesito es recorrer el primer archivo1 y si el texto de la cuarta columna concide con la primera columna del archivo 2 copiar esa linea al archivo especificado en la columna dos del mismo archivo (col2. archvivo2) si no hay coincidencia se mandaria a un archivo en una ubicacion /tmp/otras

Comment: Y necesariamente quieres hacerlo en bash? me entran ganas de resolverlo con PHP o con node.

Comment: Tu [anterior pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55972/83) es parecida y podrías usar parte de la solución (a la que no diste información sobre si te funcionaba o no). ¿Qué intentaste, Kevtho? Sería bueno acompañar la descripción con una muestra del contenido de los ficheros resultantes en base a este ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar 2 while anidados del tipo:

#

```
while IFS=';' read uno1 dos1 tres1 cuatro1;do # IFS define el separador
         while IFS=';' read uno2 dos2;do 
##### Comparar los valore con 
              if [[ $cuatro1 == $uno2 ]]
              then ######## si son iguales ===>
              else  ######## si son diferentes
              fi
         done <archivo2.csv
done <archivo1.csv
```

#

OBS: no entendi bien que deseas hacer cuando son iguales,
espero te haya servido para darte luz en tu idea.

Comment: muchas gracias si son iguales lo que quiero es copiar al archivo especificado en dos2

Comment: echo uno1 dos1 tres1 cuatro1 > dos2